# Oracle query loses parallelism when filter date ranges spans more than 4 years

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing

What I am doing:
Select sum of dollars paid per year using a Fact table and a Date Dimension.

What I see happening:
When the query is run for 1 to 4 years of data the optimizer makes full use of parallelism and bloom filters and the query completes in 3 minutes.
When the query is run with 5 or more years, or with no date filter at all, no parallelism is used and the query takes 90 minutes to run.

My Questions:
 Why does adding a 5th year to the predicate, or removing the date predicate, cause the loss of parallelism? 
              How do I fix this?

Fact table:
80 million rows
Parallel Degree = 8
Date key (INCUR_DTE_S_KEY) is a number derived from to_char(INCUR_DATE,'yyyymmdd') 
Table is ranged partitioned on INCUR_DTE_S_KEY:
PARTITION "MED_2010" VALUES LESS THAN (20100101)
 ...
 PARTITION "MED_2016" VALUES LESS THAN (20160101)
 PARTITION "MED_MAXV" VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
INCUR_DTE_S_KEY is a partitioned BITMAP index

Date Dimension:
Parallel Degree = 1
27 thousand rows
No partitions
DATE_S_KEY is a BITMAP index

Scenarios:

1. Query with 1 to 4 years in the predicate. 8 parallel processes run, bloom filters applied, query completes in 3 minutes.
2. Query with 5 or more years in the predicate. Lose all parallel processes, lose bloom filter, 1 process is run, query completes in 90 minutes.
3. Query no predicate. Lose all parallel processes, 1 process is run, lose bloom filter, query completes in 90 minutes.
4. Changed dimension index to unique and increased parallelism to 8 on all tables.  Now getting 4 degrees of parallelism but no bloom filter/recognition of partitions.

---

-- SCENARIO 1

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT     D."CAL_YEAR"      AS "Incur_Year",
           SUM(F."PAID")     AS "Paid"
FROM       "F_PAID" F
INNER JOIN "D_DATE"                   D
ON         F."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY" = D."DATE_S_KEY"
WHERE      D."CAL_YEAR" BETWEEN 2011 AND 2015   
GROUP BY   D."CAL_YEAR" ; 

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());

Plan hash value: 1889948660

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |            |     5 |   110 |   117K  (2)| 00:23:31 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                 |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)           | :TQ10002   |     5 |   110 |   117K  (2)| 00:23:31 |       |       |  Q1,02 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                |            |     5 |   110 |   117K  (2)| 00:23:31 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                  |            |     5 |   110 |   117K  (2)| 00:23:31 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10001   |     5 |   110 |   117K  (2)| 00:23:31 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY             |            |     5 |   110 |   117K  (2)| 00:23:31 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                |            |    69M|  1454M|   116K  (1)| 00:23:23 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         BUFFER SORT             |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|   9 |          PART JOIN FILTER CREATE| :BF0000    |  1826 | 20086 |   241   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |           PX RECEIVE            |            |  1826 | 20086 |   241   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            PX SEND BROADCAST    | :TQ10000   |  1826 | 20086 |   241   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |        | S->P | BROADCAST  |
|* 12 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL   | D_DATE     |  1826 | 20086 |   241   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |        |      |            |
|  13 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR       |            |    80M|   847M|   116K  (1)| 00:23:19 |:BF0000|:BF0000|  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  14 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL      | F_PAID     |    80M|   847M|   116K  (1)| 00:23:19 |:BF0000|:BF0000|  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("F"."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY"="D"."DATE_S_KEY")
  12 - filter("D"."CAL_YEAR"<=2015 AND "D"."CAL_YEAR">=2011)
```

---

-- SCENARIO 2

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT     D."CAL_YEAR"      AS "Incur_Year",
           SUM(F."PAID")     AS "Paid"
FROM       "F_PAID" F
INNER JOIN "D_DATE"                   D
ON         F."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY" = D."DATE_S_KEY"
WHERE      D."CAL_YEAR" BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015 
GROUP BY   D."CAL_YEAR" ; 

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());


Plan hash value: 433333781

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |           |     3 |    72 |  3640   (1)| 00:00:44 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                          |           |     3 |    72 |  3640   (1)| 00:00:44 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                          |           |   170 |  4080 |  3639   (1)| 00:00:44 |       |       |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | D_DATE    |  2191 | 24101 |   241   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
|   4 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                | VW_GBC_5  |     1 |    13 |            |          |       |       |
|*  5 |     FILTER                              |           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   6 |      SORT AGGREGATE                     |           |     1 |    11 |            |          |       |       |
|   7 |       PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |           | 37958 |   407K|  1206   (1)| 00:00:15 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| F_PAID    | 37958 |   407K|  1206   (1)| 00:00:15 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   9 |         BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|* 10 |          BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE      | IX2F_PAID |       |       |            |          |   KEY |   KEY |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("D"."CAL_YEAR"<=2015 AND "D"."CAL_YEAR">=2010)
   5 - filter(COUNT(*)>0 AND 2010<=2015)
  10 - access("F"."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY"="D"."DATE_S_KEY")
```

---

-- SCENARIO 3

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT     D."CAL_YEAR"      AS "Incur_Year",
           SUM(F."PAID")     AS "Paid"
FROM       "F_PAID" F
INNER JOIN "D_DATE"                   D
ON         F."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY" = D."DATE_S_KEY"
GROUP BY   D."CAL_YEAR" ; 

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());


Plan hash value: 433333781

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |           |    77 |  1848 | 28859   (1)| 00:05:47 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                          |           |    77 |  1848 | 28859   (1)| 00:05:47 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                          |           |  2129 | 51096 | 28858   (1)| 00:05:47 |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | D_DATE    | 27397 |   294K|   241   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
|   4 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                | VW_GBC_5  |     1 |    13 |            |          |       |       |
|*  5 |     FILTER                              |           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   6 |      SORT AGGREGATE                     |           |     1 |    11 |            |          |       |       |
|   7 |       PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |           | 37958 |   407K|  1206   (1)| 00:00:15 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| F_PAID    | 37958 |   407K|  1206   (1)| 00:00:15 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   9 |         BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|* 10 |          BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE      | IX2F_PAID |       |       |            |          |   KEY |   KEY |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter(COUNT(*)>0)
  10 - access("F"."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY"="D"."DATE_S_KEY")
```

After some feedback, I made a few changes. I'm now getting parallelism but partitions are still being ignored.

---

-- SCENARIO 4
--
-- Changes:
-- Made D.DATE_S_KEY a unique index
-- Changed F.INCUR_DTE_S_KEY index from parallel 2 to parallel 8
-- Changed Date Dimension from parallel 1 to parallel 8
--
-- Results in parallel 4 being used but still lost bloom filter

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT     D."CAL_YEAR"      AS "Incur_Year",
           SUM(F."PAID")     AS "Paid"
FROM       "F_PAID" F
INNER JOIN "D_DATE" D
ON         F."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY" = D."DATE_S_KEY"
where D.CAL_YEAR between 2010 and 2015
GROUP BY   D."CAL_YEAR" ; 

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());


Plan hash value: 881547170

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                    | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |            |     4 |    96 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                              |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                        | :TQ10001   |     4 |    96 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                             |            |     4 |    96 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                               |            |     4 |    96 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH                            | :TQ10000   |     4 |    96 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY                          |            |     4 |    96 |  1515   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                          |            |   170 |  4080 |  1514   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR                    |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | D_DATE     |  2191 | 24101 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |         VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                | VW_GBC_5   |     1 |    13 |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 11 |          FILTER                              |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |           SORT AGGREGATE                     |            |     1 |    11 |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |            PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |            | 37958 |   407K|  1206   (1)| 00:00:15 |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  14 |             TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| F_PAID     | 37958 |   407K|  1206   (1)| 00:00:15 |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |              BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 16 |               BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE      | IX2F_PAID  |       |       |            |          |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   9 - filter("D"."CAL_YEAR"<=2015 AND "D"."CAL_YEAR">=2010)
  11 - filter(COUNT(*)>0 AND 2010<=2015)
  16 - access("F"."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY"="D"."DATE_S_KEY")
```

Comment: "DATE_S_KEY is a BITMAP index" -- isn't this a unique value? If so, a BITMAP index sounds like a quirky choice.

Comment: "INCUR_DTE_S_KEY" -- is parallelsim set on this index?

Comment: The Date_S_Key should be unique. I can/will fix that.

Comment: Yes, "INCUR_DTE_S_KEY" (and all the indexes) are parallel 2.

Comment: I'd retest after recreating that index as b-tree. Bit of a long shot, but the presence of that index and lack of unique/primary key might have put the optimiser off a bit.

Comment: An workaround would be to add a full hint: `select /*+full(d_date) full(f_paid)*/` but why is this happening is a good question.

Comment: The DATE_S_KEY is now a unique index and the query with 5+ years is parallel but it's only two process. The parallelism on the fact date index was 2, I increased that to 8 but the query still only uses 2 processes.

Answer (score 2):

According to Dani Schnider, https://danischnider.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/time-dimension-keys-and-partitioning/, it seems that Oracle, when using dates as a partition key, really wants the data type to be DATE. I was using integers based on to_char(date, ‘yyyymmdd’) as a surrogate key a la Ralph Kimball.

I switched all my date keys to actual dates, made the indexes bitmap joined, and the execution plan works for all date ranges.

```
Plan hash value: 4263234925

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                     |     4 |   100 |  5921   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                 |                     |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)           | :TQ20001            |     4 |   100 |  5921   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |  Q2,01 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                |                     |     4 |   100 |  5921   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                  |                     |     4 |   100 |  5921   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH               | :TQ20000            |     4 |   100 |  5921   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |  Q2,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY             |                     |     4 |   100 |  5921   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS             |                     |   195 |  4875 |  5920   (1)| 00:01:12 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR       |                     |  2505 | 30060 |   157   (0)| 00:00:02 |     1 |    15 |  Q2,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL      | D_DATE              |  2505 | 30060 |   157   (0)| 00:00:02 |     1 |    15 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |         VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE   | VW_GBC_5            |     1 |    13 |            |          |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 11 |          FILTER                 |                     |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |           SORT AGGREGATE        |                     |     1 |   177 |            |          |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |            PX COORDINATOR       |                     |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|  14 |             PX SEND QC (RANDOM) | :TQ10000            |     1 |   177 |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|  15 |              SORT AGGREGATE     |                     |     1 |   177 |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |               PX BLOCK ITERATOR |                     | 37958 |  6561K|  5554   (1)| 00:01:07 |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|* 17 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL| F_PAID              | 37958 |  6561K|  5554   (1)| 00:01:07 |   KEY |   KEY |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   9 - filter("D_DATE_INCUR"."CAL_YEAR"<=2015 AND "D_DATE_INCUR"."CAL_YEAR">=2009)
  11 - filter(COUNT(SYS_OP_CSR(SYS_OP_MSR(COUNT(*),SUM("F_ACTIVE_MED_CLAIMS_PART"."PAID")),0))>0 AND 2009<=2015)
  17 - filter("F_ACTIVE_MED_CLAIMS_PART"."INCUR_DTE_S_KEY"="D_DATE_INCUR"."CAL_DATE")
```

Comment: Oh, I should have spotted that. Amusingly I made the case just over 10 years ago that when you use the DATE datatype as a key value, you are effectively using a synthetic key anyway https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2005/06/28/dates-as-key-values-natural-or-synthetic/ -- which prompted a heated debate!

Comment: @Gerard, you can also accept your answer. It seems you spotted correctly the core issue of the problem.